# Python Numpy: Why is nparray[ i ][ j ] slower than nparray[ i , j ]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm initializing a numpy array and then plugging in loop values at some arbitrary location; for some reason it seems that indexing using double brackets is literally twice as slow as indexing using comma notation.

**EDIT:** Based on Mike's answer, I'd like to understand how multidimensional indexing can be implemented as a single operation, and whether there ever is a point in using the first notation.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])

def access(arr):
    for i in range(1000):
        arr[1][2] = i

def access2(arr):
    for i in range(1000):
        arr[1,2] = i        

t1 = Timer('access(x)', 'from __main__ import access, x')
print(t1.timeit(number = 1000))

0.425940990448

t2 = Timer('access2(x)', 'from __main__ import access2, x')
print(t2.timeit(number = 1000))

0.217132806778
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer

This:

```
nparray[i][j]
```

means two indexing operations.

This is essentially what happens:

```
tmp = nparray[i]
tmp[j]
```

So, you create an intermediate array `tmp` you don't need anymore later on.
This is extra work.

While this:

```
nparray[i, j]
```

is only one indexing operation. NumPy is more efficient with this method because it does not need to create any intermediate array here.

#### How it works

This is what happens when you do `nparray[i, j]`.
The class `ndarray` overrides  the special methods `__getitem__` and  `__setitem__`.
For example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __getitem__(self, indices):
...         print(indices)
...     def __setitem__(self, indices, value):
...         print(indices, value)
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a[1, 2]
(1, 2)
>>> a[1, 2] = 23
(1, 2) 23
```

You can see that the `1, 2` in `[1, 2]` arrives there as a tuple.
Now, NumPy can do  with this information whatever is appropriate.
In our case do some 2D indexing.

#### Possible use case of the slower approach

There are not many occasions for using this method:

```
nparray[i][j]
```

One of them could be when you use a list of lists for a 2D structure and also (for some reason) want to use a NumPy array as a drop-in replacement. While this is slower, the code would work with a list of lists as well as with a 2D NumPy array.

Comment: But then what's the point of ever using the first notation? is there ever one? And how is multidimensional indexing implemented as one operation?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff: `nparray.__getitem__((i,j))` vs `nparray.__getitem__(i).__getitem__(j)`

Comment: Or actually in this case, `nparray.__setitem__((i,j), val)` vs `nparray.__getitem__(i).__setitem__(j, val)`

Comment: To understand how `numpy` handles multidimensional indexing you need to know something about how arrays are stored.  You need to read documentation that talks about `data buffer`, `shape`, and `strides`.  That's beyond your current question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's compare the disassembly:

```
>>> dis.dis(access)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              34 (to 37)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                20 (to 36)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

#------------- differences start here -------------#
  3          19 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (arr)
             25 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             28 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             29 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             32 STORE_SUBSCR        
#-------------- differences end here --------------#
             33 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   36 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(access2)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 33)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

#------------- differences start here -------------#
  3          19 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (arr)
             25 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2))
             28 STORE_SUBSCR        
#-------------- differences end here --------------#
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

From this, we can see that the first version involves two extra operations (`LOAD_CONST` followed by `BINARY_SUBSCR`). Your experiment suggests that this is more expensive that doing a single subscript lookup by tuple, as done by the second function.

Comment: Thank you, it's very telling to see the disassembly. Is there ever a point in using the double indexing over the faster single indexing? And if not, do you know why they (numpy) kept it in there?

Comment: You might want to look at a 1D slice of a 2D array. The `[i]` indexing gives you precisely that.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be using Python 3 you can take advantage of `dis` accepting a string as input in py3 and do `dis.dis('arr[1, 2]')` if you'd like :) This will remove the unecessary op codes for the function call and return.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: That's useful to know, thanks!